# JUnit тест для void функции

Tags: java, юнит-тесты, junit

Надо протестировать функцию `JUnit` тестами:

```
public static void get() { 
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    try { 
        c = scan.nextInt(); 
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) { System.out.println("ERROR"); } 
}
//////////////////////////////////////////    
@Test(expected = InputMismatchException.class)     
public void test() { 
// ? 
}
```

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как это реализовать?

Comment: @theevilsscream, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: `void get()` - это шикарно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. определяем зависимости модуля (те
       переменные что использует модуль)
2. определяем значимые значения (базовые состояния) для
       каждой внешней переменной,
       используемой в тестируемом модуле.
3. набрасываем диаграмму
       причин-следствий, с указанием
       ограничений
4. зная количество переменных и
       количество их состояний узнаём
       сколько всего комбинаций будет.
5. зная количество комбинаций и тип
       переменных, определяем где и как
       лучше хранить тестовые наборы
       Hardcode, БД, Cериализаванный
       объект, json, xml, txt.
6. собираем комбинации тестовых наборов
       из значимых значений, но только те
       что
       удовлетворяют ограничениям
7. создаём поток ввода `InputStream` и
       через метод
       `System.setIn(InputStream in)`
       привязываем его.
8. в `test()` собственно перебираем
       тестовые наборы  и сравниваем
       результаты

---

пара замечаний.

1. значимых значений у `int` 7шт `0, 1, -1,
       Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE,
       Integer.MIN_VALUE/2, Integer.MAX_VALUE/2`
2. данные лучше хранить в виде Hardcode
3. сгруппировать данные в класс обёртку
       `DataSet` с методами `String getError()` и `static [коллекция<DataSet>] getData()`

Answer (score 0):

Я так понимаю "c" это поле класса, проверте его на ожидаемое значение. Чтоб покрыть блок catch, вы должны перадать в стандартный поток ввода некорректное значение. Ну а если уже совсем по честному, то так методы никто не пишет.

Answer (score 0):

Такой метод нужно не тестировать, а переписать или вообще выкнуть. Он не имеет ни смысла, ни цели.

- Это метод с `void` в сигнатуре, но он называется `get()`.
- Ещё он получает значение из `System.in`, а потом его просто теряет.
- В случае появления ошибки он съедает сообщение об ошибке и пишет бессмысленный текст в `System.out`.

Вот такой метод можно было бы тестировать:

```
public static int readInt(InputStream is) throws InputMismatchException { 
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(is);
    return scan.nextInt(); 
}
```

В тестах делаете собственный `InputStream`, ему отдаете значение, ввод которого будете эмулировать.